# Split payment using Braintree

Tags: php, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I have integrated Braintree payment gateway into my application to process payment transactions.

> I have a feature where I need to generate paycheck for other users
>   according to their preferred frequency cycle and credit their
>   respective calculated amount into their preferred payment methods such
>   as Paypal, Applepay.

Upon referring documentation of Braintree marketplace to disburse amount to multiple users we need to register user as submerchant and split payment amount into their respective accounts but our application is destined for Brazil and according to documentation of Braintree

> Braintree Marketplace is only available for business models in which
>   the master merchant and sub-merchants are all domiciled in the US. It
>   is not compatible with PayPal, Braintree's recurring billing, or most
>   third-party shopping carts.

Hence I cannot opt market place service for implementation of paycheck feature .
Please suggest me an appropriate service which I need to use to accomplish paycheck feature.
Looking forward for appropriate solution to my question.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact 
[support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

This question isn't easily answered over StackOverflow since it will depend on many things regarding your business and what you are looking for, so I would recommend emailing in to our Support or Sales team (depending on what solution you are interested in).

If you want options on possible solutions to build this functionality out yourself please contact out Support team to assist you further.

If you are looking for an alternative to our Marketplace solution and not able to build it out yourself I would recommend contacting our Sales team to discuss what options may be available for you. While our Marketplace option is no longer being offered and was only available within the US, our Sales team may have suggestions on what may work for your desired integration.